# Filter combobox on global variable

Tags: ms-access, vba, combobox, global-variables

So I have this Access 2010 database into which users must login. The username they use is saved as a global variable. I then have a form which updates a table when they enter data and click a "save" button. I am trying to set one of the comboboxes (user) that is currently linked to a column in the table to be filtered on the global variable so that each person can only enter data under their own username. Is this possible? Does anyody know how to code this? I'm a complete newbie to Access and VBA and would appreciate any help

Greets
Me

Answer (score 0):

In the form_load() function of that form you should fill the combobox with the global variable. To be sure they can't edit you should disable the combobox as well.

```
 Private Sub Form_Load()
      Me.myComboBoxName = gMyGlobalVariableName
      Me.myComboBoxName.enabled = false
 End Sub
```

However I'm assuming that the combobox has two columns (id and username) of which the first one is hidden and the primary key of some table where you store all the usernames. The     gMyGlobalVariableName should have stored the id, not the username itself.

Comment: Hi SouthLI've tried this before and it gives me an error saying I cannot set the value of the field. I think it's because the form is bound to the table in which the field is a lookup

Answer (score 0):

You can set the row source of the combo in the load event of the form to include only the relevant rows.

```
Me.TheCombo.RowSource = _
    "SELECT UserColumn, Etc FROM TheTable WHERE UserColumn ='" _
    & TheVariable & "'"
```

You may also wish to ensure that the form only contains the relevant records, however, the fact that you have a save button, suggests an unbound form. In Access, save buttons are largely redundant because the default is to save a record and stopping saves is the difficult bit.

I wonder why you do not use their windows log-in user name?

Comment: hi Remou - I am not using their windows log-in because I read that Access 2010 has no user level security and you have to code it yourself. Also I have a save button because my boss would prefer it that the users can't go back to old forms. So the form I'm using is bound to the table, but I've set it up so that none of the navigation buttons or menus are shown unless you're admin. As for you solution, it gives the same response as SouthL's.

Comment: What is the current rowsource of the combo?